# How to check BackgroundImage property of panel

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a panel named 'panel4' programatically. I use images from `Properties.Resources`. I want to check `BackgroundImage` property of panel, but my code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I have maked my program to set the `BackgroundImage` automatically. I have tried `MessageBox.Show(panel4.BackgroundImage.ToString())`, but it shows me something like this:
***System.Drawing.Bitmap***

This is some code that checks the `BackgroundImage` property, but in vain:

```cs
if (panel4.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.NoMute)
{
    return;
}
if (panel4.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.Mute)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: You want to check BackgroundImage property of panel, what exactly do you mean by that ? Do you want to set background image of your panel programatically ?

Comment: You can't afaik. Keep track of what you load when you are loading it! Maybe in the Tag of the Panel.

Comment: These Properties.Resources property getters are very dangerous.  Nobody expects them to return a *new* image object.  Since it is a new object, the comparison always fails.  Simple use a variable in your class so you retrieve the image only once.  And Dispose() it when the form is closed, something else that is routinely overlooked.

Comment: Ok, I have created bool named IsMute and everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this from this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-background-of-a-windows-forms-panel)

namespace :

```
using System.Drawing
```

code :

**EDIT :**

```
 panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Properties.Resources.xyzImage);
```

OR

```
  panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(YourImageFileName);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP isn't trying to set the image, they're trying to read it, more specifically compare it to another one.

Comment: I need to load image from Properties.Resources, not from a file located on disk.

Comment: Properties.Resources.Image is just a name for an image that is being identified when you use that in you code. path is also defined in an image resource. so basically you can use FromFile(Properties.Resources.ImageName)